# How to sort a map in scala where the key is List[Double] and the value is double. And I wanna sort with double?

Tags: scala, list, sorting, dictionary

```
var mapping: Map[List[Double], Double] = 
  Map(List(7.259784480169157E15, 1.3217906182041678E16) -> 5.935002195633169E15
     ,List(7.651141979888688E15, 1.727193653474565E15) -> 2.592248264511382E15)
```

I was trying to use this syntax there : `ListMap(mapping.toSeq.sortBy(_.2):*)`

but this is not actually working..

Comment: A couple of `_`s seem to be missing.  Try `ListMap(mapping.toSeq.sortBy(_._2): _*)`.

Comment: Side note: You may want two use a tuple/pair instead of a List if it always has exactly two entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapping.toList.sortBy(_._2).toMap
Res: scala.collection.immutable.Map[List[Double],Double] = Map(List(7.651141979888688E15, 1.727193653474565E15) -> 2.592248264511382E15, List(7.259784480169157E15, 1.3217906182041678E16) -> 5.935002195633169E15)
```

above function sorts the Map by values. Hence _._2 (values), similarly keys will be represented by _._1

Comment: code only posts are very discouraged. please some explanation.